# latex plot schematic figure?

Tags: pdftex

Can I plot the following figure with latex pdf module?[image]

Comment: The answer to the question "Can I produce the following figure with LaTeX?" is "Yes." With `tikz` it is straightforward but also tedious.

Comment: I would describe it more as a block diagram with elements from schematics.